# Hierarchical outline of project, activities, tasks, sub tasks on Windows & iOS - local sync or cloud?

Tags: windows, ios, project-management, todo

Outline project, activities, tasks, sub tasks on Windows & iOS - local sync or cloud? Prefer free.

I'm seeing some task/to-do list apps like Wunderlist and Todist that on my quick look don't seek to have a hierarchical outline.

Then there are some like Outliner/Outline which are iOS only or iOS + Mac.

It's just for personal use where I want to map out mental tasks/sub tasks to get a certain activity or personal project underway and done.

So sync (on demand) via local network/WiFi is fine. Cloud is also welcome, but that usually entails the company wanting $$; maybe freemium/free version.

Do not wish to have an app that works like web app and freezes/delays (e.g. Wunderlist slows down when the net is down or low).
So offline mode should also work.

What I've done before is used Google Docs/Dropbox + Word - with bulleted lists, but it's less than ideal.